# How do I specify the hostname SPF shows to users?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

I have a production Magento site which is on a dedicated host.  The machine has it's "hosting" name, `host-123.hosting.com`, as well as its public name, `buystuffhere.com`.  DNS has been configured for SPF email validation for emails originating from our server as well as from 3rd party mailing services.  Here's the gist of the DNS record (`1.2.3.4` being the dedicated magento server):

`v spf1 mx ip4:1.2.3.4 include:salesforce.com ~all`

With the current configuration SPF is working, but emails appear in my GMain inbox with the "from" portion showing

> STW stw@buystuffhere.com via **host-123.hosting.com**

I'd like to clean this up so that SPF displays our public name:

> STW stw@buystuffhere.com via **buystuffhere.com**

Where do I configure this?  Is it within Magento?  Is it an email setting for the hosting user?  Is it a DNS change?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd just point you at the docs, but they turned out to be rather difficult to locate, so I'll point you at the docs instead:

Google says you [need to set up both SPF and DKIM records](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182) to avoid the "via" whatever domain being displayed.

> #### I'm a sender and I don't want my recipients to see the "via" link. What can I do?
>
> Gmail checks whether emails are correctly authenticated. If your messages are sent by a bulk mailing vendor or by third-party affiliates, please publish an SPF record that includes the IPs of the vendor or affiliates which send your messages and sign your messages with a DKIM signature that is associated with your domain.

You should also get your reverse DNS fixed, and review the rest of Google's [Bulk Senders Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126).

Comment: Thanks, I'll add DKIM.  Looking into the reverse DNS aspect it looks like I'll need to have my host add a PTR record to their nameserver rather than altering my DNS records.